# How to truly undo an ill-chosen index creation?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, ssms

I am trying to cut down execution time of an SQL `SELECT` query.

So far, I had reached about 39 to 42 seconds of execution time for a given set of filter parameters that would yield a bit less than 600,000 rows.

To see how I could further improve this, I used the *Include Actual Execution Plan* feature in SSMS. SSMS suggested I add a specific non-clustered index with an `INCLUDE` clause on a table with 6.5 million entries.

Thus, I added the index as suggested. Creating the index took several minutes. Unfortunately, with the index, execution time of my query increased to over 5 minutes.

So, I deleted the index again, hoping to get back to the previous results of some 40 seconds.

**Still, execution time of my query remained at well over 5 minutes.**

Eventually, I rebooted and this was what brought back the original execution time of some 40 seconds.

**Is this a known phenomenon? Is there anything I can do to prevent it, or treat it without rebooting?**

Comment: No this isn't a "known phenomenon" Did you gather the execution plans at all stages? Before index create. After Index Create, After Index Drop, After Reboot. We need these to see what was really going on

Comment: The suggested indexes from SQL Server are not always the correct suggestions. If a query has been run (recently) its query plan will be cached, running it again will result in the reuse of said plan. You can, however, add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to your query to force it to regenerate a plan. Restarting the instances *can* remove many of the cached plans, but restarting an instance is often less than ideal.

Comment: If the statistics of your indexes are stale, SQL Server may choose an execution plan that is underperforming. You can update the statistics if you expect this to be the problem.

Also, if this is a query in a stored procedure, you might experience the negative effects of "parameter sniffing". You can use OPTION (RECOMPILE) to counter that.

Comment: how do wait stats look when your query is running ..